# Record Array to json.dumps

Tags: python, json, numpy, pandas, dump

I need to generate a json from a Pandas DataFrame, but using df.to_json shows segmentation error, so I want to find another way to create the json and the only thing I got was to create a records array from the dataframe.

Now I need to create the json.dumps with the names of the files. Something like this

```
{ "id":123, "name":"myname"}
```

This is the code I've managed to create and this is my file (http://pastebin.com/iYewEfTg):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

columns = [u'SalesOrderID', u'OrderDate', u'DueDate', u'ShipDate', u'SalesOrderNumber', u'Title', u'FirstName', u'MiddleName', u'LastName', u'Suffix', u'PhoneNumber', u'PhoneNumberType', u'EmailAddress', u'EmailPromotion', u'AddressType', u'AddressLine1', u'AddressLine2', u'City', u'StateProvinceName', u'PostalCode', u'CountryRegionName', u'SubTotal', u'TaxAmt', u'Freight', u'TotalDue', u'UnitPrice', u'ProductName', u'ProductSubcategory', u'ProductCategory']
data = pd.read_csv('../Uploads/TxtDataSimplified.txt', header=0, names=columns, sep='\t')
data2 = data.to_records(index=0)   
arrayJSON = []
for r in data2:
    for c in columns:
        d=[]
        d[c] = r.__getattribute__(c)
    arrayJSON.append(d)
```

I need a JSON like this:

```
[  
{  
   'City':'Sooke',
   'FirstName':'Devin',
   'Title':nan,
   'LastName':'Phillips',
   'SubTotal':'189,97',
   'OrderDate':'2014-06-30 00:00:00.000',
   'AddressType':'Home',
   'PhoneNumberType':'Home',
   'TaxAmt':'15,1976',
   'AddressLine2':nan,
   'AddressLine1':'2742 Cincerto Circle',
   'DueDate':'2014-07-12 00:00:00.000',
   'TotalDue':'209,9169',
   'ShipDate':'2014-07-07 00:00:00.000',
   'StateProvinceName':'British Columbia',
   'MiddleName':nan,
   'ProductCategory':'Accessories',
   'PhoneNumber':'425-555-0163',
   'CountryRegionName':'Canada',
   'PostalCode':'V0',
   'SalesOrderNumber':'SO75123',
   'Suffix':nan,
   'ProductName':'All-Purpose Bike Stand',
   'SalesOrderID':75123,
   'EmailAddress':'devin38@adventure-works.com',
   'EmailPromotion':0,
   'Freight':'4,7493',
   'UnitPrice':'159',
   'ProductSubcategory':'Bike Stands'
},
{  
   'City':'Sooke',
   'FirstName':'Devin',
   'Title':nan,
   'LastName':'Phillips',
   'SubTotal':'189,97',
   'OrderDate':'2014-06-30 00:00:00.000',
   'AddressType':'Home',
   'PhoneNumberType':'Home',
   'TaxAmt':'15,1976',
   'AddressLine2':nan,
   'AddressLine1':'2742 Cincerto Circle',
   'DueDate':'2014-07-12 00:00:00.000',
   'TotalDue':'209,9169',
   'ShipDate':'2014-07-07 00:00:00.000',
   'StateProvinceName':'British Columbia',
   'MiddleName':nan,
   'ProductCategory':'Clothing',
   'PhoneNumber':'425-555-0163',
   'CountryRegionName':'Canada',
   'PostalCode':'V0',
   'SalesOrderNumber':'SO75123',
   'Suffix':nan,
   'ProductName':'AWC Logo Cap',
   'SalesOrderID':75123,
   'EmailAddress':'devin38@adventure-works.com',
   'EmailPromotion':0,
   'Freight':'4,7493',
   'UnitPrice':'8,99',
   'ProductSubcategory':'Caps'
}
]
```

And the error that I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/python/tests2.py", line 11, in <module>                                                                                            
    d[c] = r.__getattribute__(c)                                                                                                                                  
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

But I really appreciate a help with the final result, I've been changings from error to error, but unable to get to what I want. I need the JSON to insert it in MongoDB.

Comment: Could you please provide sample snippets of both the DataFrame and the desired JSON-file? Please add them to your question as an edit. Where do you get your source data from?

Comment: You also need to include the actual error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, `d` is a list, which you are trying to index with unicode strings. You have to change this to a dictionary (`d = {}`).

However, the output still wouldn't be what you'd expect. Instead you can do this:

```
for r in data2:
    arrayJSON.append(dict(zip(columns, r.tolist())))
```

or even this:

```
arrayJSON = [dict(zip(columns, r.tolist())) for r in data2]
```

`tolist()` will convert the record `r` to a normal list containing native python values. This is so that it can be serialized by `json.dumps`. `json.dumps` may still include values such as `NaN` though, which is not actually valid JSON. You can replace these values in your DataFrame by using: 
`data.fillna(value="", inplace=True)`.

This is what it all would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

columns = [...]
data = pd.read_csv('../Uploads/TxtDataSimplified.txt', header=0, names=columns, sep='\t')
data.fillna(value="", inplace=True)
data2 = data.to_records(index=0)

arrayJSON = [dict(zip(columns, r.tolist())) for r in data2]
print(json.dumps(arrayJSON))
```